# Proper evaluation of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I was able to determine that $(x!)^{1/x}$ tends to infinity with $x$ using Stirling's approximation. My question has two parts, is this in general a valid method to determine limits and is my answer correct?

Comment: The answer is correct. The Stirling approximation is perhaps overkill.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how I could directly calculate the limit without it?

Comment: From a lower bound on $x!$ that takes less work to prove. For example it is not hard to show that $(x!)^2\ge (x/2)^x$.

Comment: Or, directly, looking at the last half of the product, $n! > (n/2)^{n/2}$.

Comment: @martycohen: Thanks, I make a remark about overkill and then overkill.

Comment: And, looking at the last $an$ terms, where $0 < a < 1$, $n! > ((1-a)n)^{an}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the limit tends to infinity, let's instead consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log(x!)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x}$$

We have
$$\log(x!) = \log x + \log(x-1) + \cdots + \log 2 \ge \int_{x-1}^x\log t \;dt + \int_{x-2}^{x-1} \log t\;dt + \cdots + \int_{1}^2 \log t\;dt$$
Since $\log t$ is increasing.  Thus,

$$\log(x!) \ge \int_1^x \log t \; dt$$

so, evaluating the integral,
$$\log(x!) \ge x\log(x) - x + 1$$

So, we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x} \ge \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\log(x) - x + 1}{x} = +\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

$\forall n ,\exists x_0 $ such that $\forall x > x_0$, $x! > n^x$ so $(x!)^{\frac1x} > n$. So by definition $(x!)^{\frac1x} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

When a limit involves
factorials
(or the Gamma function),
Stirling's formula
is usually a good way to start.

If you can get a result
by more elementary means,
you get more points from me
(which is worth what it sounds like).

And if you use evaluation
of an integral by
complex integration,
I look at it and say
"I wish I could do that."

By the way,
yes your answer is correct.